# error message on page close

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a `Visualforce Page` that will show an error message if a user tries to exit page without hitting one of the command buttons. It shouldn't trigger if the user clicks on the command buttons.

This works as long as the user doesn't try to leave page and hits 'stay on page'. Once they do this - it shows the error message no matter what button is selected.

Any suggestions?

Here is command button onclick code:

```
onclick="NoPrompt();"
```

Here is the script on page:

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2" TYPE="text/javascript">

    var allowPrompt=true;

    function unloadMessage(){
        if(allowPrompt){
            message = "Wait! Please hit 'Save and Close' before exiting the page."
        }
        else{
            allowPrompt = true;
        }
        return message;
    }

    function setBunload(on){
        window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;
    }

    setBunload(true);

    function NoPrompt()
    {
      allowPrompt = false;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Would you need to execute "NoPrompt();" every time a hyperlink is clicked to ensure the user stays in the page (appropriatly)?  Like add the onclick event for every a

Comment: I have used this successfully - https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure